# How to implement blurry text in web page correctly in term of security?

Tags: css, angular, blur

I have an angular app. There are couple of pages where visible data available only
for subscribers and not for free users.

There are couple solutions for this and I'm not sure which one is the appropriate:

1. Have one html page only (one component) can have two different divs, one with visible text (normal) and second
   with png files which include blur text.
2. Have one html page only (one component) and when the user is free user, use css the blur only the value of the field based on the user role.
3. Have two html files which mean two different angular components, one with png files (with blur text) and second component with normal visible text.

**What is my main concern**

A free user is going to the page, inspect elements and remove the css class which responsible for
making the text to be blurred.

I need to guide the frontend development team on which direction to go, can you help with this?

Comment: if you ask about security in applications then the answer will always be the same: **backend**. For the reasons that you perfectly described, security measurements has always to be done through the backend. That measn that blurring a etxt with CSS is not an option. but the entire text should never be send to the browser in the first place unless you are an authorized user.

Comment: Sidenote: Having text inside an image is neither accessible nor is it responsive.

Comment: I take the "non responsive" as a reason to discard the png files options. As for security, your note was helpful as I am able to block the data to be sent to the free user in the first place. So we still left with what to do with the free user. Is sending fake/sample data from the server and then blur it with css. Becasue the requirement is to at least show this user the length of the text he is missing (blurring of course).

Comment: I will wirte an extended answer to that as it is way to long for a comment

Comment: @user2304483 You could have a fake text that you blur but you should make sure that it won't be read by screen reader and that an alternate text explaining why the content isn't available is read, or you could have a skeleton instead, same with an text explaining why the content is not available (at least for screen reader if it's obvious for others).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you explained in your question correctly, the user always has access to the dev tools and as such can inspect all elements and manipulate them. You can make it harder for a user to inspect elements or try to uglify them, but a smart user can intercept that as well.

Websites work through GET requests. A user types in an URL and the browser will request to GET a document. The web server then will resolve the request by sending a document to the browser that will keep a copy of that document in the cache. At that point, you have no further control of that document and the user can do with it whatever he likes. He can inspect the content or the source code itself.

If you keep the process in mind you will understand, that the only way in protecting content is by blocking the request. That has to be done server-sided. In particular, you have to block unauthorized users from receiving confidential content in the first place.

### Options

##### 1. Using Images

While using images might sound smart, you have to note that images have two major downsides. 
They missing **accessibility** and **responsiveness**!

The text on an image can not be read by screen readers. For that, you need an `alt` attribute which again comes back to the point that it can be accessed by everyone.

For responsiveness it is to note that a low-resolution image will work well on low-resolution screens but terrible on high-resolution screens where the text thanks to the stretching is pixelated and no more readable. The other way around would allow readability in most cases but the image size will be not user friendly. With mobile internet speed, you might take a long time to download the image while also costing valuable limited high-speed traffic.

##### 2. Using a preview

Using a preview is common for articles and newspapers. There you will send a limited amount of the article to the free user as a teaser while cutting the rest on the backend and working with a gradient blur (`linear-gradient` with colors with alpha values such as `rgba` or `hsla`) to hide the non-existing content (the content that is not sent by the server).

```css
section {
  width: 10em;
  height: 20em;
  border: 2px dashed red;
  padding: 0.5em;
  position: relative;
}

section::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 5%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 20%);
}
```

```html
<section>
  <!-- Actual text from the restricted content -->
  <p>This is just a preview text which will be blurred after some text.</p>
  
  <!-- Text will not actually be delivered and as such also not be within the DOM -->
  <p>This Text will not be existing while it does not matter because the reader wouldn't be able to see it anyways.</p>
</section>
```

This has the advantage that the user gets a teaser and is more likely to be pushed to pay a membership to keep reading. It also works perfectly with screenreaders while you should add a screenreader-only text to explain that further content is only visible with a membership.

You could also send a fake text but I would not recommend it. Sending a teaser is more likely in generating more memberships while the fake text is needed traffic (useability concerns for users with limited mobile internet).

Comment: Hi @tacoshy , I have already implement a "teaser", this include few fields which are fully accesiable with updated and real values . As for your suggestion for implement blur, I need to get the front end team to deliver and then review. For securiry we both agreed that I won't sent the full data to free user, this will be done by creating 2 different end-points in the backend, easily. Now, you mentioned that you wouldn't recommend to send fake data, which means the remaining fields will be null, is that mean that hard coded text will be showed in the angular template?

Comment: IMHO you should not hardcode any text. If you already using an API/DAL then send I would send a JSON as an example that contains the information if it is a preview or full text and then the content that should be visible. Then you can render the document user-sided with the content that a user should be allowed to see. If the user is authorized, the server needs to validate the authorization and then return a JSON with the full text and the full information. I would not compile the entire text or article server-sided. I would rather send the information that should be displayed through the API

Comment: Sorry I didn't get the main part. If the free user doen't get fake data from the server than it means the field value is null. My requirement from front-end team is show blur text. My question is where this text come from if not hard coded OR maybe becuase of lack of knowledge, does the frontend can show blurred text without any text?

Comment: If it is fake text, then the front end can use a fake text that is hardcoded in the first place. However, if you have a preview I would combine both. Starting to blur at the end of the preview while fully blurring when there is no actual text anymore as in the snippet. However if the blur should still show something that looks like a text, you can sue Ispum dolor in the frontend that you blurr

Comment: Ok, so you recommend hard coded text and the front-end will make it blur. The "preview"  term that you refer to is not really applicable in my case becasue the content is not an article. It is a list of field. Field-Value pairs. NUmber of fileds are visible to the free user and for the other/majority the field name is visible and value will be blurred.